# PostgreSQL UPDATE statement treats keyword as a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

sorry for the noob question, just getting started with SQL and I have a problem that I could not resolve.
Basically, I created a table with "date of birth" column and chose wrong TYPE (integer), so every time I am trying to enter date of birth as "1998-01-04" it is just  showing 1998. So, I decided to update the column to TEXT type.
Tried these queries

```
UPDATE users
SET date_of_birth = VARCHAR
```

It shows me error that there are no VARCHAR columns. Tried with as 'VARCHAR', still not working, tried as 'TEXT' and TEXT, still the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll want an `ALTER TABLE` statement. Also, PostgreSQL has a [`date` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are as bad or worse than integers for this purpose.  You want to use:

```
alter table alter column date_of_birth type date;
```

Note:  If you have existing data in the column, you need to either use the `using` clause to convert it to a date.  Or `NULL` it all out.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your alter table statement

```
 ALTER TABLE users
ALTER COLUMN date_of_birth TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

I am not sure why you are storing date as varchar whereas you can store it as date, if you want to change that to date then use

```
ALTER TABLE users
ALTER  COLUMN date_of_birth TYPE DATE;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not seem to have a `CHANGE COLUMN` action ~ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Appreciate your answer 